# On the relationship between $\max(p_i)$ and $\omega(b)$, if $\sigma(b^2)/b^2$ is bounded above by a specific number $U$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, discrete-optimization

Let $\omega(x)$ denote the *number of distinct prime factors* of $x$, and let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of the divisors* of $x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$.

Let the number $b \in \mathbb{N}$ be given in the form
$$b = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(b)}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}},$$
where the $p_i$'s are primes with $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_{\omega(b)}$, and $\alpha_i \geq 1 \hspace{0.05in} \forall i \in \left[1,\omega(b)\right]$.

Then suppose that I have the upper bound
$$\dfrac{\sigma(b^2)}{b^2} < U.$$

Note that a lower bound for $I(b^2) = \sigma(b^2)/b^2$ is
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(b)}{I({p_i}^2)},$$
which, in turn, is bounded below by
$$\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(b)}{I({p_{\omega(b)}}^2)} = \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} + \left(\dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}}\right)^2\right)^{\omega(b)}$$
where $p_{\omega(b)} = \max(p_i)$ is the largest prime dividing $b$.

Letting $P = p_{\omega(b)}$ and $W = \omega(b)$, and asking Wolfram Alpha to solve the resulting inequality, gives a "**Standard computation time exceeded**" error message.

Since $I(p_{\omega(b)}) < I({p_{\omega(b)}}^2)$, we can simplify our computations at the expense of a somewhat crude estimate:
$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}}\right)^{\omega(b)} < U,$$
$$1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} < U^{1/\omega(b)},$$
$$\dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} < U^{1/\omega(b)} - 1,$$
$$p_{\omega(b)} > \dfrac{1}{U^{1/\omega(b)} - 1}.$$

Here are my questions:

> > **(1)** Is it possible to do significantly better than this?
> >
> > **(2)** If *(1)* is not possible, how can one analytically compute the lower bound for $p_{\omega(b)}$ obtained from $$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} + \left(\dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}}\right)^2\right)^{\omega(b)} < U?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a complete answer to question **(2)**.*

It turns out that it is possible to analytically compute the lower bound for $p_{\omega(b)}$ obtained from
$$\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} + \left(\dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}}\right)^2\right)^{\omega(b)} < U$$
by a simple application of the quadratic formula:
$$1 + \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} + \left(\dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}}\right)^2 < U^{1/\omega(b)}$$
Letting $p$ denote $1/{p_{\omega(b)}}$, we obtain:
$$1 + p + p^2 < U^{1/\omega(b)}$$
$$p^2 + p + \left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right) < 0$$
The critical points are at
$$p_1 = \dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2}$$
and
$$p_2 = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2}.$$
(Note that $1 - U^{1/\omega(b)} < 0$.)  Therefore, the region of validity for the inequality is
$$p_1 < p < p_2,$$
so that
$$\dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2} < \dfrac{1}{p_{\omega(b)}} < \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2}.$$
In particular,
$$\dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)} < p_{\omega(b)}$$
since the lower bound for $p = 1/{p_{\omega(b)}}$ is trivial, as
$$\dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{1 - 4\left(1 - U^{1/\omega(b)}\right)}}{2} < 0.$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$p_{\omega(b)} > \max\left(\dfrac{1}{U^{1/\omega(b)} - 1}, \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\left(U^{1/\omega(b)} - 1\right)}}{2\left(U^{1/\omega(b)} - 1\right)}\right).$$

**QED**